# How to flip an integer that represents a 8-digit hex string in Lua?

Tags: lua, hex

In my Lua script, I have a variable that stores an integer found from some function that represents a hex string. I want to flip it so that, for example, if it has a value of `0x006E57E8`, it will become `0x8E75E600`. How do I do it in Lua?

Comment: `tonumber(("%08x"):format(x):reverse(), 16)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to Skriptunoff's very concise & readable function, here's a function doing it using bit ops:

```lua
function reverse_nibbles(int)
    res = 0
    for i = 0, 7 do
        res = res | (((int >> (4*i)) & 0xF) << (28 - 4*i))
    end
    return res
end
```

This won't create a garbage string (and would hopefully be faster). You might want to hand-unroll the loop.